# audio card UNCLAIMED ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, alsa

My computer, running ubuntu 22.04, has a Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller onboard audio card and is not getting recognized by ubuntu.
On the same computer I am running windows 11 and audio works fine.

Do you know what I should do to make my ubuntu recognize the audio card to make it work properly?

Here is some information that might help, I'll gladly provide additional requested information.

**uname -r**
5.15.0-52-generic

**Here is the result from lshw -class multimedia**

```
*-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
       description: Audio device
       product: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.4
       bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.4
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0300000-c0307fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: GA102 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:41:00.1
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D11p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D12p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:307 memory:f1080000-f1083fff
```

**Running  lspci -k | grep -A 4 Audio  gives the following**

```
2e:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
40:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse Root Complex
40:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Milan IOMMU (rev 01)
--
41:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
42:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
```

**Here is the dump from alsa, running alsa-info  --stdout**

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.1
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Tue Nov  1 15:09:43 UTC 2022


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      ASUS
Product Name:      System Product Name
Product Version:   System Version
Firmware Version:  1003
System SKU:        SKU
Board Vendor:      ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Board Name:        Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0010:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0030:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/IPI0001:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:03/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C33:00/status      15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.15.0-52-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.15.0-52-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf1080000 irq 307


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

2e:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1043:874f]
41:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aef] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1459]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel
Tree:


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Nvidia GPU 9a HDMI/DP
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10de009a
Subsystem Id: 0x10de1459
Revision Id: 0x100100
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x04 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
    *Dev 00: PD = 1, ELDV = 1, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=09, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x407381: 8-Channels Digital CP
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x185600f0: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=0d, enabled=1
  Devices: 4
     Dev 00: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 01: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
     Dev 02: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
    *Dev 03: PD = 0, ELDV = 0, IA = 0, Connections [ 0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b ]
  Connection: 4
     0x08* 0x09 0x0a 0x0b
Node 0x08 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x09 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0a [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
Node 0x0b [Audio Output] wcaps 0x62b1: 8-Channels Digital Stripe
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D11p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D12p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Nov  1 11:00 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Nov  1 06:40 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Nov  1 06:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 280 Nov  1 06:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  1 06:40 pci-0000:41:00.1 -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card NVidia

Card sysdefault:0 'NVidia'/'HDA NVidia at 0xf1080000 irq 307'
  Mixer name    : 'Nvidia GPU 9a HDMI/DP'
  Components    : 'HDA:10de009a,10de1459,00100100'
  Controls      : 49
  Simple ctrls  : 7
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',5
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',6
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

removed to make it shorter

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

acpi_ipmi
aesni_intel
ahci
ast
asus_wmi
autofs4
binfmt_misc
br_netfilter
bridge
ccp
cec
cfg80211
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dca
drm
drm_kms_helper
drm_ttm_helper
drm_vram_helper
edac_mce_amd
eeepc_wmi
efi_pstore
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
hid
hid_generic
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_piix4
input_leds
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
ip_tables
ipmi_devintf
ipmi_msghandler
ipmi_si
ipmi_ssif
iwlwifi
ixgbe
joydev
k10temp
kvm
kvm_amd
libahci
libcrc32c
llc
lp
mac_hid
mdio
mfd_aaeon
msr
mxm_wmi
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_tables
nfnetlink
nft_chain_nat
nft_compat
nft_counter
nls_iso8859_1
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvme
nvme_core
overlay
parport
parport_pc
platform_profile
ppdev
pstore_blk
pstore_zone
ramoops
rapl
rc_core
reed_solomon
sch_fq_codel
snd
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_pcm
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer
soundcore
sparse_keymap
stp
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
ttm
usbhid
video
wmi
wmi_bmof
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_pin_configs:
0x04 0x185600f0
0x05 0x185600f0
0x06 0x185600f0
0x07 0x185600f0

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    1.790051] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    1.790052] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    1.790052] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    5.312285] ast: probe of 0000:2a:00.0 failed with error -5
[    5.328679] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.328753] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    5.328759] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    5.328825] snd_hda_intel 0000:2e:00.4: Skipping the device on the denylist
[    5.341168] audit: type=1400 audit(1667299222.725:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=929 comm="apparmor_parser"
--
[    5.373530] input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input15
[    5.397202] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input8
[    5.397339] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input9
[    5.397455] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input10
[    5.397542] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input11
[    5.397732] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input12
[    5.397965] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input13
[    5.398141] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:01.1/0000:41:00.1/sound/card0/input14
[    5.452233] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 1 fixed counters, 163840 ms ovfl timer


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1                        all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.6-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Comment: Does the maker of the device say it is supported by Ubuntu and have a driver for it? Unclaimed means no driver.

Comment: I don't know how to find that information, I thought that generic sound driver could be used for most of them, am I wrong?

Comment: It seems in this case yes. Start at the maker of the hardware site. Do they have a driver?

Comment: There is no driver available for the this on asus website. I have a motherboard Asus pro ws wrx80e-sage se wifi

Comment: If there is no driver and it does not work with a built in driver there is nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the sound card is actually a USB device (i.e. it connects to the motherboard via some type of USB interface), and there is a parameter called `CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO` that has to be set in the Linux kernel so that Linux knows the sound card is there.  The problem is described in [this post on Gentoo forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1144134-start-0.html).
Unfortunately, the only solution is to change the kernel configuration and then re-compile the Linux kernel (a non-trivial task).  There are a lot of posts on reconfiguring the kernel; [this one from linuxconfig](https://linuxconfig.org/in-depth-howto-on-linux-kernel-configuration) and [this one from phoenixnap](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/build-linux-kernel) are both good (be aware that you can make it really hard to boot if you screw it up badly enough).

I am still working on this problem myself so I can't swear that the solution works, although the guy on the Gentoo forum said it did.  So far, two things I've found helpful were 1) install [grub-customizer](https://itsfoss.com/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu/) to make it easy to switch between kernels at startup; and 2) be aware of the `purge` command in case you need to delete a kernel you've made.  Good luck!